# Default value for DropDownList removing controls from a div

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I've got a DropDownList which is databound to a table that has a simple descriptive text column and a column for ImageUrls.  When the user clicks chooses from the DropDownList an image is added to a div.  I have the AutoPostBack property of the DropDownList set to true so the user can have a better interaction with the page.  At first I thought things where fine, then while testing I found that if the user adds something from the dropdown, then goes back to the default text in the list item ("Select picture to add"), whatever has been added into the div will dissappear.  If the user then chooses a different picture to add, the new picture is added along with the previous one that had disappeared.  Can someone help me figure out why that is?

```
public partial class Webform1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string imageListKey = "imageListKey";
    //List of images inside the div will be stored in Viewstate to they aren't lost
    //during postback
    List<string> ImagePaths
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState[imageListKey] == null)
                ViewState[imageListKey] = new List<string>();
            return (List<string>)ViewState[imageListKey];
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //don't hit the database every time there's a postback
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from CardPictures", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    DropDownList2.AutoPostBack = true;
                    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "SideAffectName";
                    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "ImagePath";
                    DropDownList2.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DropDownList2.DataBind();
                    DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select picture to add", "-1"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //don't allow duplicate values in ImagePaths
        if (!ImagePaths.Contains(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value))
        {
            if (DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value != "-1")
            {
                ImagePaths.Add(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
                //foreach Image selected, add to testDiv
                foreach (string s in ImagePaths)
                {
                    testDiv.Controls.Add(AddImage(s));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //to test that things are being added to the ViewState variable correctly
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string s in ImagePaths)
        {
            Response.Write(s + "<br/>");
        }
    }
    //adds an Image and setes the imageUrl to whatever is in the ViewState ImagePaths
    private Image AddImage(string imageUrl)
    {
        Image i = new Image();
        i.Height = 75;
        i.Width = 75;
        i.ImageUrl = imageUrl;

        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the SelectedIndexChanged event handler:

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //don't allow duplicate values in ImagePaths
    if (!ImagePaths.Contains(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value))
    {
        if (DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value != "-1")
        {
            ImagePaths.Add(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
            //foreach Image selected, add to testDiv
            foreach (string s in ImagePaths)
            {
                testDiv.Controls.Add(AddImage(s));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You are not adding the items back to the testDiv UI control on a postback for when the user picks/selects the 'Select picture to add' (this is the foreach inside of the if (DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value != "-1").  Your code should be this:

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //don't allow duplicate values in ImagePaths
    if (!ImagePaths.Contains(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value))
    {
        if (DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value != "-1")
        {
            // Only add to the image paths list if it is not 'Select picture to add'
            ImagePaths.Add(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value);
        }
    }

    // Always put the images into the DIV
    //foreach Image selected, add to testDiv
    foreach (string s in ImagePaths)
    {
        testDiv.Controls.Add(AddImage(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: this only happens when a new drop down item is selected, it should be moved out of the selection event

Answer (score 1):

The controls are being created dynamically and not being stored in any state, (ViewState or otherwise).  The strings containing the paths are, but not the dynamic Image controls themselves.  So they never get recreated when the user selects the prompt text, which I assume returns a value of -1, and so you never rebuild the container of Images on postback

What you should do is place the for loop that builds the Image control container div in it's own method and call it during page load so it's rendered every time there is a postback and only add strings to the ImagePaths collection when the selection event is fired.